# JavaScript checkbox dropdown style not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Beginner here.
My functionality is working, but at the moment it shows the checkboxes already dropped down.
I want to hit the drop down in order to see the boxes.
Help!

```
<style>
  .multiselect {
    width: 450px;
  }

  .selectBox {
    position: relative;
  }

  .selectBox select {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .overSelect {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  #checkboxes {
    display: none;
    border: 1px #dadada solid;
  }

  #checkboxes label {
    display: block;
  }

  #checkboxes label:hover {
    background-color: #1e90ff;
  }
</style>
```

And here is the second part, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong any help would be highly appreciated.
This is the HTML.

```
<div class="multiselect">
  <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes(0)">
    <select>
      <option>Select an option</option>
    </select>
    <div class="overSelect"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="checkboxes-0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="one" value="red" />red
    <input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="two" value="blue" />blue
    <input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="three" value="green" />green


<script>
  var cbOneExpanded = false;
  var cbTwoExpanded = false;

  function showCheckboxes(id) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById('checkboxes-' + id);

    if (id > 0) {
      if (!cbTwoExpanded) {
        checkboxes.style.display = 'block';
        cbTwoExpanded = true;
      } else {
        checkboxes.style.display = 'none';
        cbTwoExpanded = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (!cbOneExpanded) {
        checkboxes.style.display = 'block';
        cbOneExpanded = true;
      } else {
        checkboxes.style.display = 'none';
        cbOneExpanded = false;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: How can a checkbox be "dropped down"? A check box is simply just that, a box that can either be checked or not checked. Without any HTML markup or screen shot, it's pretty hard to figure out what it should look like or what it actually looks like.

Comment: where and how does php come into play? not to mention no html

Comment: ok, let me update

Comment: updated. @Fred-ii- like i said, still a beginner, this is a PHP project, but i suppose there is none in this part.

Comment: if this is a php project but no php code that you may think as being irrelevant, the tag should be removed; it makes the question unclear and it's also misleading to those who follow that tag, such as I. ;-)

Comment: you can't mix select and checkboxes like that. why not a multi-select instead?

Comment: Sorry @Fred-ii- ! my bad.

Comment: i dont understand @nogad

Comment: Why is the select-element there at all?

Comment: Ok, everything was working how i wanted it, but something changed in the style. the checkboxes were hidden fine before, how theyre showing automatically instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i do not know, ive tried things until theyve worked, looked at code examples and tried to make it work. like i said im a beginner but im going through lots of trial and error. Just stuck with this one.

Comment: _"but something changed in the style"_ - What changed? For one thing, in your css, you have `#checkboxes { display: none; ... }` but your div has the ID `checkboxes-0`.

Comment: Ah, thats because i have 2 different drop downs that im attributing these styles to, so i made a checkboxes-0 and a checkboxes-1

Comment: thats why i did the ('checkboxes-' +id)

Comment: Then you should give them a (the same) class, like `<div id="checkboxes-0" class="checkboxes">` and then style the class instead of the ID: `.checkboxes { display: none; ... }`

Comment: You know what guys, i fixed it. In my style section i just changed the #checkboxes lines to #checkboxes-0, then copied and pasted those and added #checkboxes-1. Thanks lads.

Comment: If you do what I suggested in my last comment, you only need one style and you don't need to update the css every time you add a new list.

Comment: This site has guidelines for asking questions that clearly states what should and shouldn't be included. If someone post a question without following them, it clearly shows that they didn't read the guidelines or just don't care. Then people can get a bit antsy. That's because there are thousands of questions posted here everyday and good questions gets muddled out by poor questions (poor in this case is questions that doesn't adhere to the guidelines). And calling people names isn't really helping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.  First just hide the div that contains the boxes and then in your js function display the div.

```js
  var cbOneExpanded = false;
  var cbTwoExpanded = false;

  function showCheckboxes(id) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById('checkboxes-' + id);
    var x = document.getElementById('checkboxes-0');
    x.style.display = "block";
    
    if (id > 0) {
      if (!cbTwoExpanded) {
        checkboxes.style.display = 'block';
        cbTwoExpanded = true;
      } else {
        checkboxes.style.display = 'none';
        cbTwoExpanded = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (!cbOneExpanded) {
        checkboxes.style.display = 'block';
        cbOneExpanded = true;
      } else {
        checkboxes.style.display = 'none';
        cbOneExpanded = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
 .multiselect {
    width: 450px;
  }

  .selectBox {
    position: relative;
  }

  .selectBox select {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .overSelect {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  #checkboxes {
    display: none;
    border: 1px #dadada solid;
  }

  #checkboxes label {
    display: block;
  }

  #checkboxes label:hover {
    background-color: #1e90ff;
  }
```

```html
                    <div class="multiselect">
                      <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes(0)">
                        <select>
                          <option>Select an option</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="overSelect"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div id="checkboxes-0" style='display:none'>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="one" value="red"/>red
                        <input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="two" value="blue"/>blue
                        <input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="three" value="green"/>green
And here is the rest
```

Comment: You're the man! appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Check this.I don't know if it's what you are looking for but it's working.

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#checkboxes-0").css("display","none");

    flag = true;

    $(".selectBox").on("click",function(){
       if(flag){   
        $("#checkboxes-0").css("display","block");
        flag = false;
       }else{
        $("#checkboxes-0").css("display","none");
        flag = true;
       }


    });

  });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<style>
  .multiselect {
    width: 450px;
  }

  .selectBox {
    position: relative;
  }

  .selectBox select {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .overSelect {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  #checkboxes {
    display: none;
    border: 1px #dadada solid;
  }

  #checkboxes label {
    display: block;
  }

  #checkboxes label:hover {
    background-color: #1e90ff;
  }
</style>

<div class="multiselect">
  <div class="selectBox">
    <select>
      <option>Select an option</option>
    </select>
    <div class="overSelect"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="checkboxes-0">
     <input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="one" value="red" />red
     <input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="two" value="blue" />blue
     <input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="three" value="green" />green
    </div>
```